# What exactly does the drawRect: method of an UIView object do?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, drawing

I have read the official documentation and I am a bit confused. Does this method draw the view itself (what we see on the screen)?

Comment: Yes, I believe it outlines the frame of the view.

Comment: Yes. Try it out. If you want a `UIView` that shows more than a static image or background colour, you will have to override drawRect. A random Google search turned up this tutorial... http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/window-uiviewcontroller-etc/graphics/drawing-graphics-on-a-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. This method is called by the system when a view's backing layer needs to be drawn by the rendering system. [This article](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/moving-pixels-onto-the-screen/) gives a great explanation of how to method works, and how things are drawn onto the screen in general.